# Getting File Not Found exception while fetching data from an xlsx file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, apache-poi

I have 3 sheets in my excel file. I am trying to fetch data with @DataProvider annotation of TestNG.In getTestData() method, I am passing the name of sheet. Through FileInputStream, reading the path of the file. Even if I am printing the file path, it's appearing correctly.
Build path printing as - **C:\Users\Gaurav Pratap Singh\eclipse-workspace\SampleTestFrameworkGPS\src\main\java\com\crm\qa\testData\FreeCRMTestData.xlsx**. Only issue can be the space in directory name. But I am having one more file i.e. config.properties, which is perfectly picking up from same directory.

```
package com.crm.qa.util;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;

public class TestUtil extends TestBase {



    public static String TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir")
    + "\\src\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\qa\\testData\\FreeCRMTestData.xlsx";
    
    public static Workbook book;
    public static Sheet sheet;

    public static Object[][] getTestData(String sheetName){
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH));
            // File Path printing perfectly
            System.out.println("Sheet path " + TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sheet path " + TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);

        try {
            book = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sheet = book.getSheet(sheetName);

        Object[][] data = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];

        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                data[i][k] = sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(k).toString();
            }
        }
        return data;

    }

}
```

Comment: Does exception getting caught at `catch (FileNotFoundException e1)` ?

Comment: Yes @NandanA , program focus is going to this line mentioned by you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. The path you are passing is not valid I guess. Are you sure it is `\\src\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\qa\\testData\\FreeCRMTestData.xlsx"` is correct one? Can you add screenshot of project structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is was because of the path, folder **Gaurav Pratap Singh** has spaces in that. I have changed the drive which doesn't have any spaces and it worked. It's pretty weird that I was able to access config.properties file from same directory.

Comment: also please use single "/" forward slash. because when we are deploying in linux machine. it will fail on double slashes.

Comment: right Jayanth but I was using windows here. So double slash came by default.